# Live video streaming issue on Micromax A117

Tags: android

I getting some issue on live video streaming.

```
05-21 17:56:34.589: E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(136): checkExistence failed, reason [No such file or directory]
05-21 17:56:34.589: E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil(136): checkDcf: file does not exist.
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:421)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:730)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:606)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-21 17:56:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(27984):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest  me

Comment: is it running fine in all other device?

Comment: Check line num 421 of your VideoView.java file. It shows NullPointerException. Also post your code.

Comment: @Manoj, any luck with this issue?